# FaceBook Image Upload In API in iOS swift

Tags: swift, facebook, image, type-conversion

[image]

I am new in iOS . i am trying to convert image or image url into png,or jpg format and failed .plz help me in this matter

```
@IBAction func FBSignInAct(sender: AnyObject) {
        let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()

        fbLoginManager .logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], fromViewController: self, handler: { (result, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil){
                let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result
                if result.isCancelled {
                    return
                }
                if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))
                {
                    self.getFBUserData()
               }
            }
        })
    }

    func getFBUserData(){
        if((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil){
            FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                if (error == nil){
                    print(result)
                    let url = NSURL(string: result["picture"]!!["data"]!!["url"]!! as! String)
                    let email:String = result["email"] as! String
                    let id:String = result["id"] as! String
                    let name:String = result["name"] as! String
                    self.signUpFBControl(email , fbID: id , name: name , profile_PicUrl: url!)
                }
            })
        }
    }

    func signUpFBControl(email:String,fbID:String,name:String,profile_PicUrl:NSURL)
    {
        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: profile_PicUrl)
        let profilePic : UIImage = UIImage(data: data!)!
        let image:NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profilePic,1)!

        let strBase64:String = image.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
        print(strBase64)
        let dataDecoded:NSData = NSData(base64EncodedString: strBase64, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.IgnoreUnknownCharacters)!
        print( dataDecoded)
        Alamofire.request(.POST, "\(SERVERURL)fb_login", parameters: ["email": email,"fbid": fbID,"name": name  ,"profile_pic": image,"user_type":"business" ]).responseJSON { response in
            let json = JSON(data: response.data!)
            if json["msg"].string == "User Details" {

                let data = json["user_details"][0]

                print(data)

                LoginValue.sharedInstance.setUserLoginInfo(data)

                self.reachNextViewController()

            } else {
                self.alertView("Sign Up Failed", message: json["error_description"].string!, button: "Close", destructive: false,secondButton: "")
            }
            print(json["error_description"])
        }
    }
```

error says 
The profile pic must be a file of type: jpeg, jpg, png.

Comment: Please paste your code as text, not an image. Also, please be more specific than just saying *"it failed"*. What error did you receive? What have you tried so far? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: error says The profile pic must be a file of type: jpeg, jpg, png.